# Настройка php + webpack + sql

Tags: php, sql

Имеется некий фронт-енд на вебпаке, необходимо, чтобы этот ФЕ обращался к php, который обращается к базе. Подскажите, как локально настроить ПХП и SQL?

Comment: Инструкций в интернете полным полно. Какие тут могут быть сложности?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работаете локально - то можете поставить сборку сервера в духе Openserver  https://ospanel.io/ 
Эта сборка позволяем выбрать связку Apache+PHP+Mysql

Мануалов по его установке полным-полно в интернете, даже на Youtube